# How to select latest rows with the same 3 other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table that I got using:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp, metric_name, instance_id, value_sum, unit, instance
FROM
    tbl_metrics
WHERE 
    (metric_name = 'Disk Available' OR metric_name = 'Disk Percent Used') 
    AND instance != ''
ORDER BY 
    timestamp DESC
```

[image]

How do I select just the latest row where the `metric_name`, `instance_id`, and `instance` are unique?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that sample table data, or the current result? What's the expected result?

Comment: That is my current result using the query above. It goes all the way to 19000 rows, and I had to block out the instance Ids, but what I wanted to get out of it is the latest row where the 'metric_name', 'instance_id', and 'instance' is unique so that I get current value for each drive for, each instance, for both disk available and disk percent used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that [MAX() gets the max value of the column in the group when used with GROUP BY](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/Max-with-group-by.php). So, what I had to do was group the columns that I wanted unique, then add MAX() to the timestamp to effectively get the latest result

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) as timestamp, metric_name, instance_id, instance
FROM tbl_metrics
WHERE (metric_name = 'Disk Available' or metric_name = 'Disk Percent Used') and instance != ''
GROUP BY metric_name, instance_id, instance
```

Then from there, I just joined the table to itself to grab the other columns that I wanted

```
SELECT a.timestamp, b.metric_name, b.instance_id, a.value_sum, a.unit, b.instance
FROM tbl_metrics a
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp) as timestamp, metric_name, instance_id, instance
    FROM tbl_metrics
    WHERE (metric_name = 'Disk Available' or metric_name = 'Disk Percent Used' or metric_name = 'Disk Total') and instance != ''
    GROUP BY metric_name, instance_id, instance
) b
ON ((a.timestamp = b.timestamp) and (a.metric_name = b.metric_name) and (a.instance_id = b.instance_id) and (a.instance = b.instance))
ORDER BY a.timestamp
```